# Use same Azure MobileService with Windows 8 as well as Windows Phone 8

Tags: azure, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

In all, this is all I want to do: I have a Windows Store app which makes use of Azure MobileService to store data. [Here](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/colors-todo/1cd03a7e-03c1-4625-b021-fb22b3ec999b) is the app. Authentication is provided by Live SDK's Single Sign On Feature. The App was coded by following instructions [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-windows-8-dotnet/). Now, all I want is the data to be accessible via a Windows Phone 8 app. Here is what I have done. Lot's of issues seem to be involved here.

- Changed API setting to support Mobile Client Authentication on the [Live Connect Portal](https://manage.dev.live.com/Applications/Index).
- The app secret was compromised. So, I generated a new secret.
- Changed the app secret value in Azure Mobile Service portal to reflect the new secret.

Now, the Windows Store app stops working and error returned says that `The authentication signature was malformed or signed by a different key.` If I use old (and discarded) app secret in Azure portal, the Windows Store app works fine.

Second weird thing: I have coded a primary Windows Phone 8 app to make use of the same Mobile Service. This app works only when the new app secret is present in Azure portal. With old key, error returned is same as above: `The authentication signature was malformed or signed by a different key.`

How do I make both the apps work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this but both W8 and WP8 worked fine with me. I started with this guide: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-windows-8-dotnet/

I did everything else same except on step 10. I did check "Mobile Client Apps: Yes ". After that I followed this guide to create WP8 project:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-wp8/

So in your case you should just put the new clientid and clientsecret into Windows Azure and then to fix the problems with Windows 8 you should redo the step 4 of Windows 8 tutorial (Associate App with the Store....)

Comment: Two things:
1. In Windows Phone 8, you followed the authentication tutorial. What I want is Single Sign On experience. So, appropriate tutorial seems to be [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-wp8/) one. But, now that I look at the code more closely, we are just passing login obtained from Live API to Azure Mobile Service. So, as long as Live SDK works correctly, Azure *must not* have any issues, right?
2. I don't understand the last statement. Reassign what to what? How?

Comment: Thanks for the notice that I followed the wrong guide. I updated my initial answer for the right guide and explained the Reassigning better

Comment: Alright! Actually, reassigning the app would have to be followed by me pushing an update to the app, right?
On the other hand, the app started working on its own again. I think it was failing because of cached tokens/cached keys/propagation time. Just guessing!

Comment: yep, if you had already published it then reassigning would need update. if it already started to working then it must have been time based issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a little bump because in Windows 8 you need to initialize the LiveAuthClient with the URL for your Windows Azure Mobile Service (yourproject.azure-mobile.net), but in Windows Phone 8, you have to initialize the same LiveAuthClient with the ClientID provided by the Live Connect Developer Center.

If you're still having trouble email the team: mobileservices (at) microsoft (dot) com.

Comment: Oh, no! As I mentioned, the Windows 8 app was successfully coded and published. I have made that sure. Thanks for the help anyway. I'd be grateful if you could verify that the app works. Link is in the question.

Comment: Cool! let us know when WP8 is published as well!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create both Windows Store and Windows Phone apps from the same mobile service instance **and** have both use Live Connect single sign-on, you **must** register the Windows Store app **first**. Also, keep in mind that Windows Store and Windows Phone both instantiate the Live client differently (for some reason), which I keep forgetting about.

Glenn.